# Access from within a class

Tags: python-3.x

Im wondering if there is a way of accessing outside the class with an instance.
I want to the instance to be put in an array at once, when it is created.

Example.

```
class Student():

    def __init__(self,table):

        self.table = table
        global sclass
        sclass[self.table].sclass(self) # This is the challenge


def sclass_maker(num_students):
    sclass = [[] for _ in range(num_students)]
    for table in range(num_students):
        Student(table) # I want these to put them self in the "sclass"- list.
    return sclass
```

Thanks for taking the time helping!
(The reason for "global sclass" is that i first used this method when sclass was created as a global element. This do not work now, when sclass is created by the function)

Comment: What is the expected input and output? It's very unclear what you're trying to do.  You're calling your `class` like a `function` and it doesn't make sense.  You can't `sclass.sclass()` since `sclass` is not a class, and nowhere in your code does it have an `sclass()` function.  What are you trying to achieve? The more I read the more I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one easy way to solve your problem is to just make the list `sclass` a global variable (by declaring it at the start of the function `global sclass`) and then have the`__init__` function add itself to that global list

something like

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self,table):
        global sclass
        sclass[self.table].append(self)
        #rest of code ....

def sclass_maker(num_students):
    global sclass
    sclass = [[] for _ in range(num_students)]
    #rest of code ....
```

Comment: Thanks alot! The reason I use the sclass = [[] for _ in range(num_students)] is that a list represent a table, and multiple students can sit at that table. Is 

Is there any dangers by making the sclass global?

Comment: Does that resolve your issue? I still don't understand your intent but if it works that's good.  If so please accept @AntiMatterDynamite's answer.

Comment: @LarsErik as long as you only have one list and you don't need multiple lists you can have it global, also changed my answer because you explained what you actually want to do with the list